# iOS App - how do people handle Internet connection downtime to provide the best UX?

Tags: ios, react-native, user-experience

I'm about to begin building my 2nd React Native app and I'd like a friendlier way to handle any Internet connection downtime should it suddenly drop out. Currently I check for a connection when executing any Fetch call and then use try/catch to display a retry component if it failed. This renders a button which re-calls the function on-press. I'm Just curious to see how other people handle this and whether I can improve my users experience!

Answer (score 0):

I would have it retry 3 times automatically. If your app can partially function offline, then you can just show that part as offline and continue to try and update every second or so.